# jQuery: Stop() Event-handling Issue Regarding Animate() Complete

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-animate

### Let's say I have these two functions:

```
$(".a").animate(
        {"left":"100%"},
        {duration:10000, complete:function(){
             //Something is triggered!! e.g 
             alert("a");
            //Please note: In actual case it is never as simple as alert("a").
        }}
);

$(".b").mouseover(function(){
    $(".a").stop().animate({"top":"100px"},{duration:5000});
});
```

- According to these, `.a` would stop as long as `.b` is
  `mouseover`-ed and `animate({"top":"100px"},{duration:5000})` would
  be triggered.
- But I want it to `alert("a")` **once** when `.b` is `mouseover`-ed
  and then trigger `animate({"top":"100px"},{duration:5000})`.

### However, I can't set the second function this way:

```
$(".b").mouseover(function(){
        //something happens! e.g
        alert("a");
        $(".a").stop().animate({"top":"100px"},{duration:5000});
    });
```

- It would `alert("a")` **twice** if `.b` is `mouseover`-ed after `.a` done
  `animate`.

### I've tried `stop()`'s `jumpToEnd parameter` and it is not ideal

Whenever `.b` is `mouseover`-ed , `.a`'s `animte` would complete instantly and `.a` would be shifted to `left:100%`. I want it to `stop` at where it is and yet `alert("a")` before second `animate` being triggered

---

**I would be extremely grateful if someone can provide  a fast and easy solution for this!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".a").animate(
        {"left":"100%"},
        {duration:10000, complete:myAfterWork} // Use the function name only
);

$(".b").mouseover(function(){
    myAfterWork();
    $(".a").stop().animate({"top":"100px"},{duration:5000});
});

function myAfterWork()
{
  if($(".a").is(":animated"))
  {
    //Access $(".a") here and do your job

    //Note if you use $(this) in place of $(".a") it will be different 
    //when called from .a's animation than from .b's animation
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the element is **currently animating** by filtering it against `:animated`.

```
$('.b').mouseover(function () {

    // if NOT animating, then terminate
    if (!$('.a').is(':animated')) { return; }

    // carry on

});
```